# CKEditor: How to install a new skin

Tags: ckeditor, skin

I am new with CKEditor, though i find it quite amazing!
Anyway, i try on a simple site and is working fine.
The only thing is that i would like to style it.
I find that there are already nice skins like Kama or BootstrapCK-Skin (the one i prefere).
But i do not understand how to install.
I see many answer on google, i have tried many of them but no one is working with me.
That's why i am asking on Stack Overflow!

Can someone explain me how to install a new skin?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

First go to page:
http://ckeditor.com/addon/kama
and download skin. After that,
open ckeditor\skins end download file copy in to skin dir.
Go to config.js end paste   config.skin = 'kama'; 
at the end of the line, and call index page... :-)